# Как редактировать сообщение в инлайн режиме?

Tags: python, aiogram

Имеется код python aiogram:

```
@dp.inline_handler()
async def process_inline_query(query: types.InlineQuery):
    result = await get_meme.meme()
    results = [
        types.InlineQueryResultPhoto(
        id='meme',
        photo_url=result,
        thumb_url=result,
        caption='Лови мем',
        reply_markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            .add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Обновить', callback_data='refresh'))
    )
]
await bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, results)
```

И код обработчика:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="refresh")
@dp.throttled(anti_flood, rate=5)
async def refresh(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        result = await get_meme.meme()
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        buttons = [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Обновить", callback_data="refresh")
        ]
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print(call)
        await bot.edit_message_media(media=InputMediaPhoto(result), chat_id=call.inline_message_id, message_id=call.inline_message_id)
        await bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.inline_message_id.chat_id, message_id=call.inline_message_id.message_id, caption=f'⏱Мем был обновлен в: {current_time}', reply_markup=keyboard)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Мне интересна возможность редактирования фотографии в сообщении если оно было отправлено через инлайн режим.
Я пробовал использовать обычную технику как с ботами `message.chat.id` и тому подобное, но обычно получаю ошибки по типу чат не найден, или же нет такой переменной.

Если кто то из вас сталкивался и знает решенье то буду благодарен если поделитесь.